# Make GraphQL api secure

Tags: javascript, typescript, express, graphql

I started using GQL with Express (It is awesome). So I have a couple questions.

1. How can I make GQL secure so only I can access the API and playground in general. Like Instagram. You can't access their "playground".
2. When I was working with rest api, I was sending tokens trough Headers to be secure. Where to put them now?

```
  app.use(
    "/graphql",
    graphqlHTTP({
      schema,
      graphiql: true,
    })
  )
```

### Thank you.

Comment: "*You can't access Instagrams "playground".*" - how do you know they even have one?

Comment: "*I was sending tokens trough Headers to be secure*" - just do the same? GraphQL is still a HTTP API, and you do authentication in exactly the same way.

Comment: if you are using graphql only for the purpose of reducing dataset & nothing else.. then I would recommend you to checkout - github.com/restmap/restmap-node

Answer (score 3):

1. I highly suggest that you don't keep your playground open into
   production. A playground is a web app with its own complexity and thus its own vulnerabilities. See [Hacking GraphQL Playground](https://blog.escape.tech/hacking-graphql-from-the-server/)
2. Authentication is handled in GraphQL exactly the same as in REST. Actually you can even have a REST authentication over your GraphQL App. You can find a lot more information here about how to manage authentication, authorization, and access control properly in GraphQL here: [Authentication, Authorization and Access Control for GraphQL](https://blog.escape.tech/authentication-authorization-access-control/)

Answer (score 1):

For 1) the playground is toggled on or off with that graphiql flag you have there. As for securing it you would want to use a middle where that checks an incoming token of some sort and allows/rejects based on the verification of that token.

2. GraphQL works the exact same way as a REST endpoint in that respect. Tokens in the headers is the standard.